# SU privileged JNI Shared binaries

Tags: android, java-native-interface, su

How to use shared binaries which are highly dependent on admin privileges in apk. I know

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c "+command);

but this will spawn a process. I need to bind the lib with apk with same PID.

Comment: You cannot.  Something running as a different userid, such as root, must of necessity run in a different process.  You will likely need to use some form of interprocess communication (often as simple as the stdin and stdout pipes) to proxy work over to the executable running as root, and receive results back from it.  There already exist 3rd-party frameworks for doing this on root-hacked devices.

Comment: this http://nerdposts.blogspot.de/2010/11/android-superuser-shared-jni-libs.html  explain the procedure in step 2 but its not clear enough

Comment: The author of that page does not seem to know what they are doing, as their method #2 will not work without drastic changes to Android far beyond the level of what people who "root" devices end up doing - you would have to actually run the application process itself as root, and that would require modifying zygote.  The lack of followup to the comments left there strongly suggest it was an idea never implemented, likely as the author wasn't able to make it work in the the way they had mistakenly imagined it would.

Comment: Thanks for the info. but how to make use of shared libraries with root permission in apk. Is there any alternative?

Comment: No.  The program and its libraries must run as the same user, and apps do not run as root - only external helper programs do.

Comment: could please give an example of helper programs

Comment: You already did, in the body of your question.